# Empty space between layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got problem with empty space between layouts:

[image: screen]

The problem is between Id and street (that thin line) at this space click animation isn't displayed. android:layout_below would probably work here, but it can't be used for layout. That's the layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:clickable="false">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/fullCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
        android:elevation="5dp"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFullId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:text="Id"
                android:clickable="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFullStreet"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dip"
                android:paddingTop="15dp"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:text="street"
                android:clickable="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFullCity"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvFullStreet"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingStart="10dip"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:text="city"
                android:clickable="false"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingStart="10dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFullEndDate"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:text="end date"
                android:clickable="false"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvTimeFullLeft"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvFullEndDate"
                android:paddingTop="30dp"
                android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                android:text="Ważne przez: "/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I think it may be because of `paddingTop="30dp"` inside `RelativeLayout`, but I don't know how to resolve it.

Comment: `android:layout_below would probably work here, but it can't be used for layout.` What do you mean by this ?

Comment: you are passing padding value there for show spaces into view controls

Comment: Android Studio doesn't see this attribute for my RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Problem occuring because of you are setting padding in your relative layout 30dp,

Change this

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="30dp">
```

With

```
 <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp">
```

Comment: Looks different, but now animation is displayed only on date and id "row"

Answer (score 0):

I think your xml should be like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="false">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/fullCardView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"

        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFullId"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:gravity="end"
                android:paddingStart="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                android:text="Id"
                android:textSize="16dip" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFullStreet"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingStart="10dip"
                    android:paddingTop="15dp"
                    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                    android:text="street"
                    android:textSize="16dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFullCity"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvFullStreet"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:gravity="end"
                    android:paddingStart="10dip"
                    android:paddingEnd="20dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:text="city"
                    android:textSize="16dip" />
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingStart="10dp">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvFullEndDate"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:clickable="false"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp"
                    android:text="end date"
                    android:textSize="16dip" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvTimeFullLeft"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/tvFullEndDate"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingTop="30dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
                    android:text="Ważne przez: " />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: now it looks like [link](https://imgur.com/a/UEmnYf0) , I should have made it with Tab Layout :/

Comment: @SkypeDogg :what do you want in layout?

Comment: all of these Views, but with click shadow working as it should, and right now that one space stays the same (card main color)